# How to insert AdMob banner ads halfway through content?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads

I made an app with my Wordpress website using a REST API in Swift. I have implemented Google AdMob ads in my app. Now, I want to show AdMob Inline Adaptive Ads halfway in the content. This is the method I use to split content that I found on the internet:

```swift
let cont = "This is my content here"
let words = cont.components(separatedBy: " ")
let halfLength = words.count / 2
let firstHalf = words[0..<halfLength].joined(separator: " ")
let secondHalf = words[halfLength..<words.count].joined(separator: " ")

print(firstHalf)
print(secondHalf)
```

It works fine but I don't know how to insert ad after firstHalf. Can somebody please help me?

This is the code for inline adaptive banner:

```swift
let adSize = GADCurrentOrientationInlineAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(320)
let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: adSize)
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
let request = GADRequest()
bannerView.load(request)
```

I have tried to add this code in a function and then using something like this:

```swift
firstHalf + inlineAds() + secondHalf
```

However, this did not work.

Comment: As far as I know [AdMob](https://developers.google.com/admob) is used only for mobile ads. You said you have a website, which means you should be using [AdSense](https://adsense.google.com/start/).

Comment: If you're in fact creating an iOS app, please specify if you're using UIKit or SwiftUI.